# Permissions in android for reading and writing storage

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I am trying to access audio files.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

are these two lines enough in the Manifest file for file permissions for all android versions?.
I watched some tutorials some of them are checking permissions in their Java classes. Someone please explain what are those.

Comment: Those are called runtime permission. It is added from Android 6 for ensuring better security and privacy in Android. If you want to support for Android version 6 or more, you have to implement Runtime permission

Comment: Thanks for your reply.does these run time permissions will be asked everytime a user opens their apps.

Comment: No if you accept once, it won't ask again until manually disable the permission from the setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are these two lines enough in the Manifest file for file permissions
>   for all android versions?

No they wont be enough as in marshmallow api 26 or higher you will need to give permission at run time